# How do I extract values from a do-while loop after each iteration in C programming language?

Tags: c, iteration, do-while

For example, I would like to extract the value of `test1` after each iteration in the code below and store them in variables as `test1a`, `test1b`, `test1c` and so on.

```
int main(void)


{
    long test, test1;

    test = 378282246310005;

    test1 = test % 10;

    printf("test = %li\n", test1);

    do
        {
            test = test / 10;
            test1 = test % 10;
            printf("test = %li\n", test1);
        }
    while (test > 10);
}
```

Comment: Use an array and an incrementing index inside the loop. `long my_array[MAX]; int i = 0; do { test1=blah; my_array[i++] = test1; }`

Comment: Array is tricky, then you might need to guess the size of the array in advance. Mind that.

Comment: @MarioTheSpoon not really. So long as you are dealing with 64-bit integer values, the most number of digits an unsigned value can contain is 20. Choosing an array size of 32 more than covers that case.